# Watir locate button not working

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Folks,

This is the code snippet from my web page:

```
<tr class="group">
<td id="group_All" colspan="4">
<form class="h" method="post" action="/item/items/555/groups">
<div style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: inline;">

</div>
<fieldset>

</fieldset>
<fieldset class="buttons">
<span>
<input type="submit" value="Group" name="commit">
or
<a onclick="$$('td.tools a').each(function(e) { e.removeClassName('highlighted') }); $('group_All').hide();" href="javascript:void(0);">Cancel</a>
```

I am trying to click on this button from the above code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Group" name="commit">
```

I tried this, which has worked in the past:

```
@browser.button(:name, "commit").click
```

But this is not working for the above button, anything else that I should be trying, thanks a lot.

Comment: I just checked on latest version of watir-webdriver and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a form.submit? I think it will support identifiers of class, method, and action (and multiple).

```
@browser.form(:action => '/item/items/555/groups').submit
@browser.form(:class => 'h').submit
@browser.form(:method => 'post').submit
@browser.form(:action  => '/item/items/555/groups', :class => 'h', :method => 'post'
```